# ImageMagick c# how to find out how many pages in pdf file api

Tags: imagemagick

Is there a api method in ImageMagick I can call to see how many pages are in an PDF file?
I am coding in .Net Core.
I would like to know how many pages are in pdf file without having using the read api where a magickimage object is create for every page in the pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Magick.NET you can use the `PdfInfo.Create` method to get the page count of a PDF file.

Comment: Really. A create method would sound like I was creating a a file,. Thanks I will try it.

Comment: That did the trick. And it did it with a quick response time, Thank you

Comment: Does Magick.Net have similar method for microsoft word document, text file, rich text file?

Comment: It doesn't have that have support for that.